# Simplify expression with assumptions involving relations between variables in SymPy

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

Is it possible to simplify an expression in SymPy, if we know that variables satisfy certain equation?
For example in Mathematica we can write something like this:

```
Simplify[a+b-c, a+b==c]
```

Of course in this case it is possible to solve for `a` and make a substitution. However, for the long expressions making a global substitution might not make a sense. If the goal is to produce the shortest expression possible, one might need to apply substitution for the certain terms and leave the rest untouched or solve for `b` instead of `a`.

I think `sympy.assumptions` module  cannot impose restrictions mutually on the several variables.
Is it possible to achieve the functionality of Mathematica's `Simplify[expr, assum]` in any other way in SymPy?

Or is there any other open-source project which can do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SymPy's current assumptions system can not handle relationships between variables although that is being worked on. There are a couple of ways that you can do this though.

The `ratsimpmodprime` function simplifies an expression that is polynomial in some symbols based on knowing that the symbols themselves satisfy polynomial equations. We can use this to make a function that simplifies the example you showed:

```py
In [26]: a, b, c = symbols('a:c')

In [27]: polysimp = lambda expr, eqs: ratsimpmodprime(expr, groebner(eqs).exprs)

In [28]: polysimp(a + b - c, [a + b - c])
Out[28]: 0

In [29]: polysimp(a + b, [a + b - c])
Out[29]: c

In [31]: polysimp(a**4 + b - c, [a**2 - b, b - c])
Out[31]: 
 2
c
```

You can also introduce a new symbol and solve for that along with the other equations as a combined system:

```
In [33]: solve([z - (a + b - c), a + b - c])[z]
Out[33]: 0
```

This method has the advantage that you can choose which symbols you want to eliminate e.g.:

```
In [38]: solve([z - (a + b), a + b - c], [z, c])[z]
Out[38]: a + b

In [39]: solve([z - (a + b), a + b - c], [z, b])[z]
Out[39]: c
```

Either answer is valid since `a + b == c` so the expected output from "simplifying" is ambiguous.

Comment: There is an issue here (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720#issuecomment-312437508)  about using `solve` to eliminate variables.